# In bash I have to ask for each row from first csv file, second csv file and the answers put to third csv file

Tags: shell-script, csv-simple

In bash I have to ask for each row from first csv file, second csv file and the answers put to third csv file ...

first file. e.g. `aaa.csv`:

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
aaa
ccc
fff
aaa
```

second file, e.g. `bbb.csv`:

```
aaa;111
bbb;222
ccc;333
ddd;444
eee;555
ggg;666
```

third file, e.g. `ccc.csv`:

```
aaa;111
bbb;222
aaa;111
aaa;111
ccc;333
fff;
aaa;111
```

Is this possible?
At this blank place can be FALSE word or something.
When I use the `cat bbb.csv | grep -f aaa.csv > ccc.csv` then take the answer with part of the common the `aaa.csv` ... only once there is aaa with the 111.

Comment: Is it possible in bash? Yes, but I think you'll want to use `awk` instead. I'm not familiar enough with it to answer; however, my understanding is the man page is *really really* useful to learn awk.

Comment: Search the site for `join`, `awk`, `sed` etc solutions. This has been beaten to death.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible approach as in comments could be using `awk` with changed order of files:

```
awk -F';' 'FNR == NR { m[$1] = $2; next; } { if ($1 in m) { print $1 ";" m[$1]; } else { print $1 ";FALSE"; } }' bbb aaa
```

First we read file bbb store values in array with keys values of first column, than we read file aaa and check if key exists in array and print accordingly.
Result:

```
aaa;111
bbb;222
aaa;111
aaa;111
ccc;333
fff;FALSE
aaa;111
```

Comment: I need to learn awk ... it's very hard for me :(

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
while read linea
do
grep "$linea" bbb.csv >> ccc.csv || echo "$linea:FALSE" >> ccc.csv
done < aaa.csv

$ cat ccc.csv 
aaa;111 
bbb;222 
aaa;111 
aaa;111 
ccc;333 
fff:FALSE
aaa;111
```

Comment: the best way for me :) thx

Answer (score 1):

How about some meta-sed:

```
sed "$(sed 's^\(.*\);\(.*\)^s/\1/\1;\2/;tx^;$as/.*/&;FALSE/\n:x' bbb.csv)" aaa.csv
```

The inner sed expression transforms `bbb.csv` into a sed program like this:

```
s/aaa/aaa;111/;tx
s/bbb/bbb;222/;tx
s/ccc/ccc;333/;tx
s/ddd/ddd;444/;tx
s/eee/eee;555/;tx
s/ggg/ggg;666/;tx
s/.*/&;FALSE/
:x
```

This is then interpreted by the outer sed to transform `aaa.csv` to the required output:

```
aaa;111
bbb;222
aaa;111
aaa;111
ccc;333
fff;FALSE
aaa;111
```

Note the `tx` in the generated sed program.  These are sed conditional jumps to the `x:` label if the preceding `s` substitution matched.  This allows a catch-all statement to be inserted last to substitute the "FALSE" text.

The caveat with this answer is it won't scale to large `bbb.csv` files, as the whole of the generated program is passsed on the command line.  If this is a concern, the generated program could be put in a temporary file instead:

```
sed 's^\(.*\);\(.*\)^s/\1/\1;\2/;tx^;$as/.*/&;FALSE/\n:x' bbb.csv > bbb.tmp.sed
sed -f bbb.tmp.sed aaa.csv > ccc.csv
```

This will still be limited if `bbb.tmp.sed` ends up really big - I think sed will attempt to read the whole of this file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend writing this particular script in Python instead of any shell tool, simply because Python's standard library includes a CSV parser that actually handles all of the wacky wrinkles in CSV syntax.  You would do something like this:

```python
import csv
import sys

# sys.argv[1] = "aaa.csv", sys.argv[2] = "bbb.csv"
# sys.argv[3] = default value for mapping
# output written to stdout

with open(sys.argv[2], "rt") as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f, dialect="unix", delimiter=";")
    mapping = { row[0] : row[1] for row in rd }

with open(sys.argv[1], "rt") as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f, dialect="unix", delimiter=";")
    wr = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect="unix", delimiter=";",
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for row in rd:
        wr.writerow([row[0], mapping.get(row[0], sys.argv[3])])
```

and then run it as e.g. `python munge.py aaa.csv bbb.csv "" > ccc.csv`.

In general, if it is not obvious how to do something in a shell script, consider *not doing it in a shell script*.  Unless portability to arbitrarily crusty installations is more important than *anything else* (e.g. in the guts of an Autoconf macro) you will be happier writing Perl, Python, Ruby, node.js, etc.

Comment: your comments are very helpful ..